# Identify the upload status

Tags: perl

I am uploading the folder from local to FTP using perl Net::FTP::Recursive module. I have written the sample code below. In that code I need to know the status of the uploading process like whether it has been uploaded or not.

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP:recursive;

my $ftp_con= Net::FTP::Recursive->new('host.com',Debug=>0);
$ftp_con->login('username','password');
$ftp_con->rput('d:\my_test','\root\my_test');
$ftp_con->quit;
```

In the above code I am unable to find the status of the uploading. Can anyone suggest me to get the uploading status of the folder, whether the folder has been uploaded or not.

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclass `Net::FTP::Recursive` to override `_rput`. Add a callback hook to the end of the `foreach` block and pass in the current file `$file` and the list of files `@files` as arguments.

In the main part of the code, count up each time the callback is called and calculating the progress from the counter and the number of elements in `@files`.

Comment: Sorry Daxim.. I can't understand clearly.. Can you please explain the steps clearly if possible..

Answer (score 0):

First thing did you remember what is your folder name that you transfer via ftf. If the transfering is so fast and you are unable to monitor wether it is already in the server, you can use anothet method to verify it wether it is successfully loaded.
1. Log in to CPanel of your website via your hosting provider
2. Locate legacy file manager folder then click
3. Choose document root for, the click Go, then start to see find your folder name that you tranfer via ftp.